# With Rails 3 view inheritance, is it possible to call "super" within a child view, but send the parent variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, asset-pipeline, view-inheritance

Every `show` action in my app has the same template for every model (it is an Admin-portal type interface). I have a view `show.html.erb` that all of these models inherit.

The controllers all use InheritedResources, so I have access to some helper variables such as `resource`, which I use to display the attributes for the model being shown through `resource.attributes` in my parent view.

What I would like to be able to do is whitelist which attributes are being shown in each model. I have thought of two ways to do this... the first is to define some method in a class my model's inherit from, say it is called `attr_visible` and define each attribute in the model. The reason I don't like this approach is that it puts too much of the view logic in the models. I would rather provide my views with the model, and let the view determine what is displayed.

The second approach is what this question is about. I want to have a file `/app/views/users/show.html.erb`, and set which attributes for a User I would like to be shown, say something like:

```
@attributes = [:name, :email, :etc]
```

And then pass them to the parent view which I described in the beginning of this question. That view would then be able to loop through `@attributes` and display the attributes necessary.

Is it possible to use a "`super`"-type method from views? Everything I have read about view inheritance suggests the view is loaded based on where it is located in the directory structure, and then after that you're out of luck.

edit: I have sort of done what I want. I defined a partial _show.html.erb in the /app/views/users directory that looks like:

```
<% @attributes = ['name', ...] %>
```

And then in the parent view I call `<%= render "show" %>` before looping through `@attributes`. This works, but feels clunky since I am not actually rendering anything when I call `render`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a presenter for this. Adding "view" logic to a model is better done through this type of object. Take a look at [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

Once the resource is decorated, you can just call `visible_attributes` or whatever. Of course, you would need to implement that method for each resource.

Views inheritance works when looking for a view, not when rendering it. Take a look at the [original plugin implementation](https://github.com/kch/inheritable_templates/blob/master/lib/inheritable_templates.rb).

Other way would be to make the `show` parent view to call `render` on `resource` and create several partials for the classes.

For a better understanding on Rails Views, I recommend [The Rails View: Create a Beautiful and Maintainable User Experience](http://pragprog.com/book/warv/the-rails-view)